# Reading specific columns from a csv without Pandas inferring headers

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to the read specific columns from a csv file in with `pandas.read_csv` in Jupyter Notebooks. I know what row the data I am interested in begins on and am using the `skiprows` keyword to go to that row, which contains the column labels.

However, even though I specify which columns I want using `usecols`, Pandas only drops the values from the columns, not the columns themselves. Thus, if my `test.csv` looks like this:

```
*first 6 rows to be skipped*
1,2,3,4,5,6
a,b,c,d,e,f
A,B,C,D,E,F
```

the snippet (after importing the correct modules)

```
df = pandas.read_csv('test.csv', skiprows = 5, usecols = np.r_[0, 2:7])
```

gives

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
a,nan,c,d,e,f
A,nan,C,D,E,F
```

instead of the desired

```
1,3,4,5,6
a,c,d,e,f
A,C,D,E,F
```

I've read through the documentation for `pandas.read_csv` and don't see an indication for how to get the desired result.

**ETA**: I am trying to get Pandas (or Jupyter Noteooks) to exclude columns from the data frame, not just the value that the columns contain.

Comment: why not usecols = [1,3,4,5,6]?

Comment: Because I was using dummy data. The actual data has me selecting over a range which I do not want to type out ever value for.

And the real issue is that ```read_csv``` is not the ***columns*** I want it to drop, only the values therein.

Comment: I think the reason is that you have the `header`... After setting the `header`, your `df` now consider the full length of col_names as `1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6` so when you only select columns `[0, 2:7]` instead of dropping it, the values will be turned to `NaN`... I suggest just dropping the column after reading the csv.

Comment: @Seraph Wedd ```read_csv``` does have a default value of ```infer``` for the  ```header``` keyword, but when I set ```header``` to ```None```, it uses the first line of data as the header.

Comment: `np.r_[0,2:7]` gives 6 values, not 5 as expected. Shouldnt it be `np.r_[0,2:6]` ?

Comment: @calestini That's not really the issue I want resolved. I'm want to drop entire columns from the data frame not just the values they contain.

Comment: I meant that when you use `np.r_[0,2:7]` you are keeping 6 columns, not 5 columns of data.

Comment: I run your code and it works when reading your sample data. It excludes the second column. Mind sharing your pandas version?

Comment: Yeah, I'm beginning to think that it is the particular environment in which I am running it, because it fails at different point, depending which environment I'm using. The particular problem I'm having occurs when I use CoCalc (www.cocalc.com), but not when I use Repl.it (repl.it).

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like below where you specify all columns you want to keep.

```
df.loc[:, ["1", "3", "4", "5", "6"]]
```

Or you could go below this which will drop just the specified column.

```
df.drop(["2"], axis=1)
```

Comment: I think that it is the "IDE" I'm using

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with the example you have given me and noticed that the number of columns that you want to read is `6`, that is `1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6`, whereas the `usecols` you entered uses `6` entries too, which are indices `0, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6`. In other words, you are using nonexistent columns, that is why it turns to `NaN`.

With `test.csv` having contents as:

```py
1-5: *skip*
6:  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6
7:  a,  b,  c,  d,  e,  f
8:  A,  B,  C,  D,  E,  F
```

I tried it with your given data and this is the result:

```py
df = pandas.read_csv('test.csv', usecols = [0, 2:6], skiprows=5)
print(df)
```

Which yields:

```py
   1  3  4  5  6
0  a  c  d  e  f
1  A  C  D  E  F
```

On the other hand, your original code:

```py
df = pandas.read_csv('test.csv', usecols = [0, 2:7], skiprows=5)
print(df)
```

Yields:

```py
   1  2  3  4  5    6
0  a  c  d  e  f  NaN
1  A  C  D  E  F  NaN
```

For this, you can also just drop the column:

```py
df.drop(['6'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.columns = ['1', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

Comment: Which "IDE" are you using?